# Images "sink" animation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, canvas, storyboard

I have my Storyboard animation which is moving images to specific (Canvas.SetTop) coordination. I wonder if there is an option to make those images go to specific coordination but make them sink NOT dissapear.
I am using DoubleAnimations in Storyboard.

```
 DoubleAnimation myAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
 myAnimation.SpeedRatio = 3;
 myAnimation.AutoReverse = false;
 myAnimation.From = 0;
 myAnimation.To = 700;
 myAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
 myAnimation.BeginTime = beginTime;
 this.beginTime += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
```

Comment: What do you mean "sink"? Do you mean move down?

Comment: Its already moving down. I mean if images is moving and when it reaches for example 200 then image is slowly dissapearing like sinking You know what i mean ?:P. Its like`re playing in casino and fruits are going down and slowly dissapear.